# How to generate a new function name from an other one

Tags: python

Let us give an example.
If we have a function `def f(func): ...`, where `func` is a parameter corresponding to a function.
If we make the following call `f(merge)`, I would like to return another function name (not a text) `merge_ext` that could be then executed.

I have identified the fact that a function name col be extract with the syntax `my_function.__name__`, but how can I generate the new function name that could be used as a function?

Comment: `eval` will change the text to a function call but you probably want error handling to make sure the function exists and you should probably sanitise inputs.

Comment: Why can't you just do `merge_ext = f(merge)` ?

Comment: merge is inside the variable func and it could be another value so we have to use func. How?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to chain two functions to create a new, combined function. This could be achieved using `functools.partial`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're after *decorators*.

A decorator is a function that takes a function as arguments, and returns a function. Simple example :

```
def simple_decorator(func):
    return func
```

You can use it with the `@` syntax :

```
@simple_decorator
def decorated_function(some_arg):
    return something
```

In that case, calling `function` will call the function returned by the call `simple_decorator(function)`, which means you cannot access the orginal `function` anymore.

But this can also be expressed like this :

```
def no_yet_decorated_function(some_arg):
     return something

decorated_function = simple_decorator(no_yet_decorated_function)
```

Now, you can access both your functions.